# Scraping websites with python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape [this website](https://fr.investing.com/indices/france-40-historical-data) to download all historical values of `CAC40` for last 2 years using python. I'm using BeautifulSoup and urllib.request

The problem is this site applies by default only one month range of dates (e.g. `20/05/2017 -> 20/06/2017`). When I change this range like `20/05/2015` to `20/06/2017`, the website doesn't change at all, it's always the same.

When I run python code, I can't take all values `CAC40` from `20/05/2015` to `20/06/2017`, as I want. It only returns values from `20/05/2017` to `20/06/2017`

Hope my question is clear and any idea for help is really appreciated.

Comment: Could you use another service like [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EFCHI/history?p=%5EFCHI)? You can download data directly from their site as a CSV without needing to scrape it.

Comment: What are you using for web scraping? That would tell which method to use.

Comment: @DanielMessias: Yes. but i don't want to do that everyday because i not only want to download CAC40 but also for other financial indices, values that Yahoo doesn't support. Before we could use pandas_datareader in python but now it seems doesn't work

Comment: @KaushikNP i'm using BeautifulSoup and urllib.request for scraping

Comment: Did you try using selenium?

Comment: @Jeril: No. i didn't know that. what's its use for? would appreciate if you go for more details.

Comment: check out [this](http://www.techbeamers.com/selenium-webdriver-python-tutorial/)

Comment: Selenium seems excessive here. A quick look at the website through the dev console and it appears that data is requested using an AJAX form and POST method. This can all be emulated using Requests.

Comment: @Jeril I see what you mean. selenium can help to directly interact with the page. It means it can automatically choose range of dates... But when i look at the source code of this website, even when i change dates, the source code seems doesn't change.

Comment: i'm not sure can totally understand what you mean @DanielMessias.

Comment: I had a look at the site, the front is designed in such a way that it does not update based on URL. To change the date we need to click the `data picker` and give the date. This manual action can be done using `selenium`, and later you can get the page source using selenium and scrap your content using beautifulsoup. NOTE: if you want it with [Google Finance](https://www.google.com/finance?cid=9237947) I have the code for it. It even provides [historical](https://www.google.com/finance/historical?cid=9237947&startdate=Jun+2%2C+2014&enddate=Jun+20%2C+2017&num=30&ei=ZwFJWen6LcjNuATr35iYAQ)and RT